# Creating Load Balancer for kube-api server with High Availability Kubernetes Cluster

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes

I am trying to create a High availability Kubernetes cluster for my CI/CD pipeline for deploying my Spring Boot microservices.

I am following the following kubernetes official document for exploring:

https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/independent/high-availability/

My confusion is that - when reading, I found that need to create Load Balancer for kube-api server for forming the HA cluster. Actually I am planning to use AWS Ec2 machines for forming the cluster. So I will get Elastic Load Balancer from AWS. So do I need to create separate Load balancer as described in document or can I use the ELB for the same ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use only ELB for this purpose.

Hopefully these [Kubernetes and ELBs, The Hard Way](https://medium.com/@hagaibarel/kubernetes-and-elbs-the-hard-way-c59a15779caf) instructions will be useful for you.